# php getElementsByTagName with nodeValue returns evil characters

Tags: php, getelementsbytagname, nodevalue

I have some utf-8 html like this:

`<a href="http://example.com">Today&nbsp;11:12&nbsp;AM</a>`

And `getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue` returns this:

`TodayÃ‚Â 11:12Ã‚Â AM`

I am not having any problems with other nodes in this html.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source documents are ASP and IIS.

I ended up using this for the offending characters:

```
str_replace( chr(), chr(), $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to explicitly set the encoding for the DOMDocument Object:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```